# How to seamlessly proxy an https site to http for testing purposes?

Tags: proxy

I have to use a variety of different servers at times that are preconfigured with their own self signed certs, over which I have no control.

I also uses various clients to connect to these servers, and each of these clients requires a unique way of importing the self signed cert to avoid security errors.

To avoid this situation, I'd like an easy way to proxy any https url to http, using whatever tool makes it easy to do so.

What can I use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [montebank](http://www.mbtest.org/) to do this. It installs very easily, is cross platform, and can do way more than solve this simple problem. I've wrapped up the process in a script, which can do things like the following:

```
$ proxy_site_using_montebank proxy 3444 https://www.test.com                        
proxying https://www.test.com at http://localhost:3444

$ proxy_site_using_montebank list                                                   
{
  "imposters": [
    {
      "protocol": "http",
      "port": 3444,
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:2525/imposters/3444"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

$ proxy_site_using_montebank requests 3444                                          
{
  "protocol": "http",
  "port": 3444,
  "name": "easyproxy3444",
  "requests": [],
  "stubs": [
    {
      "responses": [
        {
          "proxy": {
            "to": "https://www.test.com",
            "mode": "proxyAlways",
            "predicateGenerators": [
              {
                "matches": {
                  "path": true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:2525/imposters/3444"
    }
  }
}

$ proxy_site_using_montebank unproxy 3444                                           Stopped proxying port 3444
```

Here's the script:

#### proxy_site_using_montebank

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function show_help()
{
  IT=$(cat <<EOF
  
  This script uses montebank to help setup a proxy 
  on your local machine to a another webserver. It
  ignores certificate errors, so it's an easy way to
  quickly work around SSL site errors when testing using
  clients that don't know about a sites SSL cert.

  usage: proxy   PORT URL  -> proxy an url at an port
         unproxy PORT      -> stop proxying an url at a port
         list              -> list urls being proxied 
  e.g.

    proxy 3000 http://www.google.com -> Proxy google.com at http://locahost:3000
    unproxy 3000                     -> Stop proxying on port 3000
    list                             -> List active proxies
    requests                         -> Show a dump of all requests/responses made to a proxy

EOF
)
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

OP=$1
MB_SERVER=${4:-http://localhost:2525}

function ensureMontebankRunning()
{
  OUTPUT=$(curl -s $MB_SERVER/imposters 2>&1)
  if [ "$OUTPUT" == "" ]
  then
    echo "Please start montebank first. Run 'mb' with any options you want to start it up"
    exit;
  fi
}

ensureMontebankRunning

function getInitProxyData()
{
IT=$(cat <<EOF
{
  "imposters": [{
      "protocol": "http",
      "port": $EXPOSED_PORT,
      "name": "easyproxy$EXPOSED_PORT",
    "stubs": [{
    "responses": [{
        "proxy": {
        "to": "$URL_TO_PROXY",
        "mode": "proxyAlways",
        "predicateGenerators": [{ "matches": { "path": true } }]
        }
    }]
    }]
  }]
}
EOF
)
echo "$IT"
}

VALID=FALSE
if [ "$OP" == "proxy" ]
then
  if [ -z "$3" ]
  then
    show_help
  fi

  EXPOSED_PORT=$2
  URL_TO_PROXY=$3

  OUTPUT=$(curl -X PUT $MB_SERVER/imposters -d "$(getInitProxyData)" 2>&1)
  echo "proxying $URL_TO_PROXY at http://localhost:$EXPOSED_PORT"
  exit;
fi

if [ "$OP" == "unproxy" ]
then
  if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    show_help
  fi

  EXPOSED_PORT=$2
  OUTPUT=$(curl -s -X DELETE $MB_SERVER/imposters/$EXPOSED_PORT 2>&1)
  echo "Stopped proxying port $EXPOSED_PORT"
  exit;
fi

if [ "$OP" == "requests" ]
then
  VALID=TRUE
  EXPOSED_PORT=$2
  if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    show_help
  fi

  OUTPUT=$(curl -s $MB_SERVER/imposters/$EXPOSED_PORT 2>&1)
  echo "$OUTPUT"
  exit;
fi

if [ "$OP" == "list" ]
then
  OUTPUT=$(curl -s $MB_SERVER/imposters 2>&1)
  echo "$OUTPUT"
  exit;
fi

show_help
```